# RegEx to capture multi-line text body

Tags: python, regex

So I have some text documents that look like this:

```
1a  Title
        Subtitle
            Description
1b  Title
        Subtitle A
            Description
        Subtitle B
            Description
2   Title
        Subtitle A
            Description
        Subtitle B
            Description
        Subtitle C
            Description
```

I am trying to capture the 'Description' lines, which are indented by 3 tabs, using regex.  The problem I am having is sometimes the description line will wrap to the next line and be indented by 3 tabs again. Here is an example:

```
1   Demo
        Example
            This is the description text body that I am
            trying to capture with regex.
```

I am wanting to capture this text in one group, to end up with:

```
This is the description text body that I am trying to capture with regex.
```

Once I am able to do this I would also like to 'flatten' the documents, making each section on one line delimited by characters instead of lines and tabs. So my example code would become:

```
1->Demo->->Example->->->This is the description text...
```

I will be implementing this in Python but any regex guidance would be much appreciated!

**UPTADE**
I have changed the delimiters in the flattened text to indicate it's previous relation. ie; 1 tab `->`, 2 tabs `->->`, 3 tabs `->->->` and so on.

In addition, here is how the flattened text should look if there are multiple Subtitles (subsections) per Title (section):

> 1a->Title->->Subtitle->->->Description
>  1b->Title->->Subtitle
>   A->->->Description
>  1b->Title->->Subtitle B->->->Description
>   2->Title->->Subtitle A->->->Description
>  2->Title->->Subtitle
>   B->->->Description
>  2->Title->->Subtitle C->->->Description

Basically just 'reusing' the parent (number/title) for each child (subtitle).

Comment: When the line wraps, is there a new line character at the end of it or it just prints like that ?

Comment: @Sniffer - Yes, the lines wrap with \n.

Comment: Do you use tabs `\t` or spaces?

Comment: @Vik2015 - They are \t, not spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without a regex:

```
txt='''\
1\tDemo
\t\tExample
\t\t\tThis is the description text body that I am
\t\t\ttrying to capture with regex.
\t\tSep
\t\t\tAnd Another Section
\t\t\tOn two lines
'''

cap=[]
buf=[]
for line in txt.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('\t\t\t'):
        buf.append(line.strip())
        continue
    if buf:    
        cap.append(' '.join(buf))
        buf=[]
else:
    if buf:    
        cap.append(' '.join(buf))      

print cap
```

Prints:

```
['This is the description text body that I am trying to capture with regex.', 
 'And Another Section On two lines']
```

The advantage is that the distinct sections separately indented with 3 tabs remain separable.

---

OK: Here is a complete solution in regex:

```
txt='''\
1\tDemo
\t\tExample
\t\t\tThis is the description text body that I am
\t\t\ttrying to capture with regex.
2\tSecond Demo
\t\tAnother Section
\t\t\tAnd Another 3rd level Section
\t\t\tOn two lines
3\tNo section below
4\tOnly one level below
\t\tThis is that one level
'''

import re

result=[]
for ms in re.finditer(r'^(\d+.*?)(?=^\d|\Z)',txt,re.S | re.M):
    section=ms.group(1)
    tm=map(len,re.findall(r'(^\t+)', section, re.S | re.M))
    subsections=max(tm) if tm else 0
    sec=[re.search(r'(^\d+.*)', section).group(1)]
    if subsections:
        for i in range(2,subsections+1):
            lt=r'^{}([^\t]+)$'.format(r'\t'*i)
            level=re.findall(lt, section, re.M)
            sec.append(' '.join(s.strip() for s in level))

    print '->'.join(sec)
```

Prints:

```
1   Demo->Example->This is the description text body that I am trying to capture with regex.
2   Second Demo->Another Section->And Another 3rd level Section On two lines
3   No section below
4   Only one level below->This is that one level
```

### Limitations:

```
1) This is limited to the format you described.
2) It will not handle reverse levels properly:
    1 Section 
         Second Level
             Third Level
         Second Level Again       <== This would be jammed in with 'second level'
    How would you handel multi levels?

3) Won't handle multiline section headers:

    3    Like
         This
```

Running this on your full example:

```
1a  Title->Subtitle->Description Second Line of Description
1b  Title->Subtitle A Subtitle B->Description Description
2   Title->Subtitle A Subtitle B Subtitle C->Description Description Description
```

You can see that the second and third levels are join, but I do not know how you would want to handle that formatting.

Comment: I up voted this for the 'clean' method without using RegEx that does exactly what I asked. What about the document 'flattening' portion..?

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx so you're *not* looking specifically for a regex, you just want a parser? could have said earlier ;)

Comment: @robertklep - I <i>am</i> looking for RegEx in case I need to move into another programming language, however, drewk provided a simple and effective parser that I am considering using because he did provide me with what I asked for, just not RegEx. :)

Comment: @drewk - Yes yes yes, now we are getting somewhere! Question: is there a way to change the first tab to be `->` like the rest? So `1a  Title` would be `1a->Title`. I'm still working on the handling rules so more to come on that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is a trivial change. Just change `print '->'.join(sec)` to `print re.sub(r'(^\d+\w*)\s*', r'\1->', '->'.join(sec))`

Comment: @drewk - That did the trick, thanks! Also, see my **UPDATE** to the question. Thanks again for all of your *awesome* help!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
re.findall(r'(?m)((?:^\t{3}.*?\n)+)', doc)
```

It will also capture the tabs and newlines, but those can be removed later.

Comment: This is not capturing both lines. Here is what I am getting: `['\t\t\tThis is the description text body that I am\n']`

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx it works for me :) this is what I tested with: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f8d3dee9c266e96d5a5b)

Comment: @robertklep, It doesn't work for me too. I get the same output: `re.findall(r'(?sm)((?:^\t{3}.*?\n)+)', text.replace(" "*4, "\t")) ===> ['\t\t\tThis is the description text body that I am\n']`

Comment: Are you both using Windows? I'm on Mac.

Comment: @robertklep, Linux, Fedora 18

Comment: @robertklep - Windows

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx in that case, try replacing `\n` in the regex with `\r\n` to make sure it isn't caused by Windows line endings :)

Comment: @robertklep - using `\r\n` returns empty. :(

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx strange! Oh well, hopefully one of the other solutions will work better for you :)

Comment: @robertklep, soo weird... When i copy-pasted from your gist, it magically worked!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Using `re` python2:</strike>

```
text = "yourtexthere"
lines = re.findall("\t{3}.+", text)
```

Without tabs `"\t"`:

```
text = "yourtexthere"
lines = [i[3:] for i in re.findall("\t{3}.+", text)]
```

To get the final output:

```
...<br>
"\n".join(lines)
```

---

### Fix:

Not very good yet, but I am working on it:

```
import re
text = "..."
out = [i for i in re.findall("\t{2,3}.+", text.replace("    ", "\t"))]
fixed = []
sub = []
for i in out:
    if not i.startswith("\t"*3):
        if sub: fixed.append(tuple(sub)); sub = []
    else:
        sub.append(i)
if sub:
    fixed.append(tuple(sub))
print fixed
```

Comment: I like this but it is still capturing the lines in groups. `['This is the description text body that I am', 'trying to capture with regex.']`

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx, `"\n".join(lines)`

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx, Sorry! Read your question wrong. Gonna try to fix the answer now